# F# split array of strings and return the result of split

Tags: f#

```
let total = [| "1X2"; "3X4"; "5X6" |]

let oddEven = total
            |> Array.map(fun x -> x.Split('X'))
```

I have an array of string, which is total in above example, I want to split the array by "X", as the oddEven in the above example, but I want to return 2 arrays of strings:

`let odd = [| 1; 3; 5 |]` and `let even = [| 2; 4; 6 |]`

It could be an easy task, but I can not figure it out now.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check whether each string can split into two pieces, and unzip the result:

```
let total = [| "1X2"; "3X4"; "5X6" |]

let odds, evens = total |> Array.map (fun x ->  match x.Split('X') with
                                                | [|odd; even|] -> odd, even
                                                | _ -> failwith "Wrong input")
                        |> Array.unzip;;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great code!
Besides, it is very good that your code did a careful condition check, otherwise, there could be some wrong input to ruin the results!
Thanks and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Assuming this is numeric odd and even - above solution will not work correctly for            let total = [| "2X1"; "3X4"; "6X8" |]

Comment: I assume the solution is for odd and even positions in each split string array.

Answer (score 2):

```
let evens, odds = total 
                  |> (Array.map (fun x -> x.Split('X')))
                  |> Array.concat
                  |> Array.partition (fun s -> int s % 2 = 0)
```

EDIT: As John Palmer points out in the comments, you can use Array.collect instead of map and concat:

```
let evens, odds = total 
                    |> Array.collect (fun s -> s.Split('X')) 
                    |> Array.partition (fun s -> int s % 2 = 0);;
```

Comment: |> (Array.map (fun x -> x.Split('X')))
  ----^^
stdin(26,5): error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Comment: @swapneel - I think it's an indentation problem - try indenting the lines after the first so they level with 'total' in the first.

Comment: @Lee - You can youse `Array.collect` rather than `Array.map ... |> Array.concat`

Comment: @JohnPalmer - Thanks, I wasn't aware of `collect`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let odd = 
    oddEven |> Array.map (fun x -> x.[0])
let even =
    oddEven |> Array.map (fun x -> x.[1])
```

Comment: x.[1] is always 'X' and wouldn't really work with numbers larger than 9

Comment: You might just have misunderstood? oddEven is [|[|"1"; "2"|]; [|"3"; "4"|]; [|"5"; "6"|]|]